# Delete existing zip file

Tags: php, zip

I have a working code which can download all images from a website. I grab all the images, put them in a cache folder, create the zip file and download them. The problem what I can't solve is to delete the zip after I downloaded it. Here is my code:

```
foreach($image as $im){
    $info = explode('/',$im);
    $file_name = 'cache/'.$info[count($info)-1];
    copy($im,$file_name);
    $to_zip[] = $file_name;
}
// Zipping
$result = create_zip($to_zip,'kepek.zip');

// Clear cache
$files = glob('cache/*');
foreach($files as $file) if(is_file($file)) unlink($file);

// Download
Header('Location: kepek.zip');
```

Comment: Check the permissions of the file that you want do delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unlink after the header

```
foreach($image as $im){
    $info = explode('/',$im);
    $file_name = 'cache/'.$info[count($info)-1];
    copy($im,$file_name);
    $to_zip[] = $file_name;
}
// Zipping
$result = create_zip($to_zip,'kepek.zip');

// Clear cache
$files = glob('cache/*');
foreach($files as $file) if(is_file($file)) unlink($file);

// Download
Header('Location: kepek.zip');
unlink('Location: kepek.zip');
```